# innerHTML doesn't interpret HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace the contents of a div with some piece of HTML. However the html is not interpreted. If `error[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` contains `blah <strong>foobar</strong>` then I will see `<strong>` in the output. How can I fix this?

```
document.getElementById("booking").innerHTML = "Server error: " + error[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is perhaps `error[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` escaped? you could try:

```
document.getElementById("booking").innerHTML = "Server error: " + unescape(error[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```